# Mesos: mesos-slave offer additional ports

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, marathon

I've got some mesos-slave nodes that I would like to expose to the internet. As such, I would like mesos-slave to offer port 80 and 443 in addition to its default slew of ports/resources.

From [what I have gathered](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/attributes-resources/), I need to adjust the `--resources` parameter and include both 80 and 443 in the port resource offerings. However, from my tests, in doing this, I must also hard-code the machine's CPU/Mem/Disk offerings as well (as opposed to allowing mesos-slave to determine these at runtime).

Because the size of nodes I want to run `mesos-slave` on may change in the future, I want to avoid hardcoding the CPU/Mem/Disk offerings and let them be determined at runtime. **How do I change mesos-slave's port `--resource` offerings without hardcoding the CPU/Mem/Disk offerings?** Ideally such a system would be additive: "offer port 80/443 in *addition* to the default ports".

Best!

Advait

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even after specifying the ports resource Disk, CPU, Mem should be added automatically (see log excerpt) below.

```
mesos-slave.sh --master=xxxx:5050 --resources=ports:80
I0503 20:48:04.999114 2057073408 main.cpp:200] Starting Mesos slave
I0503 20:48:05.000370 243535872 slave.cpp:316] Slave resources: ports(*):80; cpus(*):8; mem(*):15360; disk(*):470848
```

Unfortunately the ports are not additive anymore... Maybe one idea could be to specify an new resource for those ports (you should be sure nothing else outside mesos uses these ports). I.e. you could be to specify --resources=port80:1;port443:1.

```
build joergschad$ bin/mesos-slave.sh --master=xxxx:5050 --resources=port80:1
I0503 20:58:52.742509 119599104 slave.cpp:316] Slave resources: port80(*):1; cpus(*):8; mem(*):15360; disk(*):470848; ports(*):[31000-32000]
```

Comment: Thanks @js84! I was actually running into issues with checkpointing. I guess a slave can't resume from a checkpoint if its resources have changed (even if the new resources are a superset of the old ones).